# Dynamic checkbox - FormGroup inside a formGroup contains formArray

Tags: angular

I use https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular
as a reference to dynamically add checkbox list.

My form structure is like:

```
 userForm:new FormGroup({
          attributes: new FormGroup({
           roles:new FormArray([])
      })

   })
```

As per addCheckboxlist in that link, I have rewritten as,

```
 private addCheckboxes() {
    this.roles.map((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl(i === 0); 
      ((this.userForm.controls.attributes as FormGroup).controls.roles as FormArray).push(control);
    });
  }
```

Now i ain't sure how to loop in html for getting those checkboxes. Please assist.

Edit:
in TS:

```
 rolesInCompany=[{
  id:"org1",
  name:"ABC"
},{
  id:"org2",
  name:"DEF"
}];
```

In HTML:

```
<label formArrayName="roles" *ngFor="let role of userForm.controls.attributes.controls.roles.controls; let i = index">
          <input type="checkbox" [value]="rolesInCompany[i].name" [formControl]="role">
          {{rolesInCompany[i].name}}
        </label>
```

On submit, I get roles: Array[true,true] when i select both. I require names instead.

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question contains a code demo in Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stszta

Here *app.component.html* is

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.orders.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
    {{orders[i].name}}
  </label>

  <div *ngIf="!form.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question yet. answer should have been userForm.controls.attributes.controls.roles.controls. in ngFor. I am able to get checkbox now. , I only get 'true' and 'false' values. Can you please help solving the same

Comment: If you add `<pre>{{ userForm.value | json }}</pre>` to your HTML you'll be able to see the form data. Are you looking to access or set the check boxes? Access if I recall would be `userForm.controls.attributes.controls.roles.controls[i].value`, set via `userForm.controls.attributes.controls.roles.controls[i].setValue(true)`

Comment: in response i get roles: Array[true,true] on selection of both. But i actually need value of those.

Comment: I need values of selected checkboxes on submit

Comment: leave if off allen. behavior is that way only

Comment: you could add a `(change)="someMethod(i)"` to the input checkboxes or push a FormGroup and not just a single FormControl to the FormArray

Answer (score 0):

You can try template from HTML itself,

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes" value="{{checkbox}}" />
```

Comment: yea i tried so. checkboxes are now visible but it shows true for selected and false for ones which are not. anyway to fetch the value selected?